# OpenMP and array summation with Fortran 90

Tags: openmp, multidimensional-array, fortran90, do-loops

I'm trying to to compute pressure tensor of a crystal structure.
To do so, I have to go throught all pair of particle like in the simplify code below

```
  do i=1, atom_number      ! sum over atoms i
   type1 = ATOMS(i)
   do nj=POINT(i), POINT(i+1)-1  ! sum over atoms j of i's atoms list
       j = LIST(nj)
       type2 = ATOMS(j) 
       call get_ff_param(type1,type2,Aab,Bab,Cab,Dab)
       call distance_sqr2(i,j,r,VECT_R)
       call gettensor_rij(i,j,T)
       r = sqrt(r)
       if (r<coub_cutoff) then
          local_sum_real(id+1) = local_sum_real(id+1) + ( erfc(alpha_ewald*r) 
          derivative = -( erfc(alpha_ewald*r)
          ff = - (1.0d0/r)*derivative  
          STRESS_EWALDD = STRESS_EWALDD + ff * T  ! A 3x3 matrix    
          FDX(i) = FDX(i) + VECT_R(1) * ff
          FDY(i) = FDY(i) + VECT_R(2) * ff
          FDZ(i) = FDZ(i) + VECT_R(3) * ff
          FDX(j) = FDX(j) - VECT_R(1) * ff
          FDY(j) = FDY(j) - VECT_R(2) * ff
          FDZ(j) = FDZ(j) - VECT_R(3) * ff     
       end if                                  
   end do               ! sum over atoms j 

   sum_kin = sum_kin + ATMMASS(i) * (VX(i)**2 + VY(i)**2 + VZ(i)**2)  
   call gettensor_v(i,Q)
   STRESS_KINETIC = STRESS_KINETIC + ATMMASS(i) * Q

 end do
```

I tried to parallelized this double loop with the "paralle do" directive but got some issue with the tensor STRESS_EWALDD and the forces FDX ....
I therefore tried to assign manualy to each thread a number of particles like in the follwing code but still get the wrong tensor value.

```
!$omp parallel  private(id,j,i,nj,type1,type2,T,Q,r,VECT_R,derivative,Aab,Bab,Cab,Dab,ff)

 id = omp_get_thread_num()      
 do i=id+1, atom_number,nthreads       ! sum over atoms i
       type1 = ATOMS(i)
       do nj=POINT(i), POINT(i+1)-1  ! sum over atoms j of i's atoms list
           j = LIST(nj)
           type2 = ATOMS(j) 
           call get_ff_param(type1,type2,Aab,Bab,Cab,Dab)
           call distance_sqr2(i,j,r,VECT_R)
           call gettensor_rij(i,j,T)
           r = sqrt(r)
           if (r<coub_cutoff) then
              local_sum_real(id+1) = local_sum_real(id+1) + ( erfc(alpha_ewald*r) 
              derivative = -( erfc(alpha_ewald*r)
              ff = - (1.0d0/r)*derivative  
          local_STRESS_EWALDD(id+1,:,:) = local_STRESS_EWALDD(id+1,:,:) + ff * T    
          FDX(i) = FDX(i) + VECT_R(1) * ff
              FDY(i) = FDY(i) + VECT_R(2) * ff
              FDZ(i) = FDZ(i) + VECT_R(3) * ff
              FDX(j) = FDX(j) - VECT_R(1) * ff
              FDY(j) = FDY(j) - VECT_R(2) * ff
              FDZ(j) = FDZ(j) - VECT_R(3) * ff     
           end if                                  
       end do               ! sum over atoms j 

   local_sum_kin(id+1) = local_sum_kin(id+1) + ATMMASS(i) * (VX(i)**2 + VY(i)**2 + VZ(i)**2)  
   call gettensor_v(i,Q)
   local_STRESS_KINETIC(id+1,:,:) = local_STRESS_KINETIC(id+1,:,:) + ATMMASS(i) * Q

 end do               ! sum over atoms i

!$omp end parallel

 do i=1,nthreads  
   sum_real = sum_real + local_sum_real(i)
   sum_virial_buck = sum_virial_buck + local_sum_virial_buck(i)
   STRESS_BUCK = STRESS_BUCK + local_STRESS_BUCK(i,:,:)
   STRESS_EWALDD = STRESS_EWALDD + local_STRESS_EWALDD(i,:,:)   
   sum_buck = sum_buck + local_sum_buck(i)
   sum_kin  = sum_kin + local_sum_kin(i)
   STRESS_KINETIC = STRESS_KINETIC + local_STRESS_KINETIC(i,:,:) 
 end do
```

Scalars and STRESS_KINETIC values are correct but the STRESS_EWALDD is wrong and I can't figure out why.
I've no idea about forces so far.
So I'd really appreciate  some hit here.
Thanks,

```
      Éric.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have taken a somewhat unorthodox approach to using OpenMP.

OpenMP provides the `reduction(op:vars)` clause that performs reduction with `op` over local values of the variables in `vars` and you should use it for `STRESS_EWALD`, `sum_kin`, `sum_real` and `STRESS_KINETIC`. Force accumulation for the *i*-th atom should work since atoms in the Verlet list `POINT` are ordered (you took the code that builds it from the book from Allen & Tildesley, right?) but not for the *j*-th atom. That's why you should perform reduction on them too. Don't worry if you read in some older OpenMP manual that reduction variables have to be scalar - newer OpenMP versions support reduction over array variables in Fortran 90+.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(....)
!$OMP& REDUCTION(+:FDX,FDY,FDZ,sum_kin,sum_real,STRESS_EWALDD,STRESS_KINETIC)
!$OMP& SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC)
do i=1, atom_number      ! sum over atoms i
 type1 = ATOMS(i)
 do nj=POINT(i), POINT(i+1)-1  ! sum over atoms j of i's atoms list
     j = LIST(nj)
     type2 = ATOMS(j) 
     call get_ff_param(type1,type2,Aab,Bab,Cab,Dab)
     call distance_sqr2(i,j,r,VECT_R)
     call gettensor_rij(i,j,T)
     r = sqrt(r)
     if (r<coub_cutoff) then
        sum_real = sum_real + ( erfc(alpha_ewald*r) 
        derivative = -( erfc(alpha_ewald*r)
        ff = - (1.0d0/r)*derivative  
        STRESS_EWALDD = STRESS_EWALDD + ff * T  ! A 3x3 matrix    
        FDX(i) = FDX(i) + VECT_R(1) * ff
        FDY(i) = FDY(i) + VECT_R(2) * ff
        FDZ(i) = FDZ(i) + VECT_R(3) * ff
        FDX(j) = FDX(j) - VECT_R(1) * ff
        FDY(j) = FDY(j) - VECT_R(2) * ff
        FDZ(j) = FDZ(j) - VECT_R(3) * ff     
     end if                                  
 end do               ! sum over atoms j 

 sum_kin = sum_kin + ATMMASS(i) * (VX(i)**2 + VY(i)**2 + VZ(i)**2)  
 call gettensor_v(i,Q)
 STRESS_KINETIC = STRESS_KINETIC + ATMMASS(i) * Q

end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Using dynamic loop scheduling will reduce the load imbalance when the number of neighbours to each atom varies wildly.

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks again. Now, I'm trying to port this part of my code to OpenACC. Since you seem the only who is able to help me I'd like to send you what I did in private if you don't mind.

Comment: I'm sorry - I have zero experience with OpenACC. I might be able to help you only concerning OpenACC-related problems that could be resolved using common HPC knowledge. I would recommend that you rather post more specific questions publicly on SO.