# OpenMP over Summation

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, fortran90, gfortran

I have been trying to apply OpenMP on a simple summation operation inside two nested loop, but it produced incorrect result so far. I have been looking around in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332619/openmp-parallel-numerical-integration-summation-performance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811302/openmp-and-array-summation-with-fortran-90), also in [here](http://www.nic.uoregon.edu/iwomp2005/iwomp2005_tutorial_openmp_rvdp.pdf). All suggest to use `reduction` clause, but it does not work for my case by producing very large number which leads to `segmentation fault`.

I also tried this way posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257887/openmp-f90-95-nested-do-loops-problems-getting-improvement-over-serial-impleme) and my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421249/openmp-for-dependent-variables) which has been solved. Both do not use `reduction` and simply just set summation variable as `shared`, but it also produces incorrect result. Is there something that I am missing? When to use `reduction` and not using that while facing summation operation?

Codes using `reduction` clause

```
index = 0
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(iy,ix) REDUCTION(:+index)
do iy = 1, number(2)
    do ix = 1, number(1)
        index = index + 1
        xoutput(index)=xinput(ix)
        youtput(index)=yinput(iy)
    end do
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Code without using `reduction` clause

```
index = 0
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(iy,ix) SHARED(index)
do iy = 1, number(2)
    do ix = 1, number(1)
        index = index + 1
        xoutput(index)=xinput(ix)
        youtput(index)=yinput(iy)
    end do
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Comment: It should probably read `REDUCTION(+:index)`...

Comment: In the second version, where `index` is shared amongst the threads, the line `index = index + 1` leads to a race condition!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a mis-conception of what the `reduction` clause does...

```
REDUCTION(+:index)
```

means, that you will have the correct sum `index` **in the end**. In each step of the iteration, each tread will have a different version with different values! So the reduction is not suitable to manage array indices during the parallel section.

Let me try to illustrate this...

The following loop

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(iy) REDUCTION(+:index)
do iy = 1, number(2)
  index = index + 1
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

is (more or less) equivalent to

```
!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(iy, privIndex) SHARED(index)
!$OMP DO
do iy = 1, number(2)
  privIndex = privIndex + 1
end do
!$OMP END DO

!$OMP CRITICAL
index = index + privIndex
!$OMP END CRITICAL
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

You can see that during the loop all threads work on different variables `privIndex` which are private to that thread, and calculate local (partial) sums. In the end, the total sum is taken, using a `critical` section to avoid race conditions.

This might not be what the compiler does, but it gives you an idea how a reduction works: at no point within the first loop does `privIndex` correspond to the correct index you would expect in the serial version.

---

As Vladimir suggests in his comment, you can calculate the index directly as you are only incrementing it in the inner loop:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(iy,ix, index)
do iy = 1, number(2)
    do ix = 1, number(1)
        index = (iy-1)*number(1) + ix
        xoutput(index)=xinput(ix)
        youtput(index)=yinput(iy)
    end do
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Comment: So `reduction` works as some kind of synchronization to ensure the value of summation at end of the loop is correct? I just want to make sure, it is also incorrect to put `index` in private, isn't it? because the value of summation should be in sequence not distributed over threads?

Comment: Reduction works exactly as @AlexanderVogt describes it, private copies of the variable are reduced at the end of the construct. Private also does not help, you would have no synchronization and you would get some values of `index` duplicated.

Comment: @FrankyDjutanta Why don't you just compute `index` from `ix` and `iy`?

Comment: Oh ya I just took the simplest one as the code was initially developed for serial, didn't think of it before. Thank you very much both of you. Much appreciated.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt, you forgot to set number(1) in `private` since it is reused inside the loop.

Comment: @FrankyDjutanta making `number` private is not required.

Comment: I agree @AlexanderVogt, I was wrong in checking the code before where I got incorrect result without putting `number(1)` in private and got the correct one with putting that in private, but it turned out that I commented `!$OMP` on the second try. I have tried the code correctly now, but it seems to delete the value of `xoutput` and `youtput` as I tried to do `write(*,*)` it showed nothing while it is okay when compiling in serial.